# Java applet with JOGL and/or LWJGL - with natives for every OS

Tags: java, opengl-es, applet, jogl, lwjgl

I am currently developing an applet for some OpenGL ES stuff but I am absolutely unsure how I can handle the natives that comes with JOGL and/or LWJGL.

LWJGL has a nice applet loader which can load jars (containing the natives) over the internet. The advantage of LWJGL is, that it has only on native pack for each platform and not one for 32bit and 64bit. Disadvantage is, that LWJGL doesn't support OpenGL ES, it just supports OpenGL (correct me if I am wrong).

So I plan to use the applet loader from LWJGL but implementing the OpenGL ES with JOGL. The big disadvantage is here, that I have no idea how I can change the natives for 32bit and/or 64bit. The applet loader just takes one jar for the natives and the natives have the same name, so I can't create a bundle which has 32bit ans 64bit support.

Trying to run the 32bit natives on my 64bit Ubuntu doesn't work, it crashes with the error of a wrong header in the files... so wrong version, I guess.

I have no idea how I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find a example with a short description for JOGL 2 on http://jogamp.org:
http://jogamp.org/jogl-demos/www/applettest-jnlp.html
(native lib deployment is basically handled automatically if you use the provided jnlp)

Comment: When I look at the sample applet, there is nowhere a native lib handled. Even the JNLP has no reference to it.

Comment: the output in the java console shows that it is loading all the native stuff. Thanks!

Comment: no problem. The jnlp references another jnlp via the extension mechanism which does all the deployment for you.